# Cross-referencing predicate for Realm queries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

So I have been learning Realm in Swift lately and I come across with a design problem regarding a potential notification between data models. It would be greatly appreciated if someone is willing to shed some insight.

```
// Class A is what users mainly interact with
Class A: Object {
    dynamic var propertyA = ""
    dynamic var propertyB = ""
    dynamic var propertyC = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "propertyA"
    }
}

// Class B is what the server interacts with, like data feeding
Class B: Object {
    dynamic var propertyA = ""
    dynamic var propertyX = ""
    dynamic var propertyY = ""
    dynamic var propertyZ = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "propertyA"
    }
}
```

I have set a notification block for `Object A` inside the controller. So whenever changes take place in `resultObjectsA`, the notification block will get triggered.

```
let resultObjectsA = realm.objects(A).filter('predicate1')
let notificationTokenA = resultObjectsA.addNotificationBlock {
    ...
}
```

In the app that I am building, the user can select a set of `Object A`, and the app will query the status of the selection set from the server. The return results will be stored/presented in `Object B`. Now, I need to write a query/predicate for `Object B`:

```
let resultObjectsB = realm.objects(B).filter('predicate2')
```

such that `propertyA` in `resultObjectB` entries can be found in `propertyA` in `resultObjectsA` entries, like a one-to-one mapping.

I am not sure if such predicate is doable. If there are other ways to achieve what I would like to do here, I am more than keen to learn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query all (actually there should be able one object because of primary key) objects `B` where `objectB.propertyA == objectA.propertyA` use:

```
let resultObjectsB = realm.objects(B).filter('propertyA = %@', objectA.propertyA)
```

Another option is to use One-to-One relationship between `A` and `B`, learn more at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-one-relationships